# SGID Bit prevents from changing to that directory

Tags: linux, chmod, acl

I have a problem which makes no sense in my mind. Could you please give me a hint what im doing wrong?

I have a folder called files which has those rights:

```
# ls -lart | grep files
drwxrws---+  19    2102 fileadmin      4096 Aug  9  2019 files
```

One user can access this directory and one with exactly the same unix group cannot.

```
# id alex (is able to cd into that directory)
uid=2665(alex) gid=4000(all) groups=4000(all),4008(fileadmin)

# id julia (is not able to cd into that directory)
uid=2905(julia) gid=4000(all) groups=4000(all),4008(fileadmin)
```

What am i doing wrong here? Here are file access control lists for this directory

```
# getfacl files

# file: files
# owner: 2102
# group: fileadmin
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:backup:rwx
user:37:rwx
user:systemd-resolve:rwx
user:2710:r-x
group::rwx
group:fileadmin:rwx
group:4016:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:systemd-resolve:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. I did remove that SGID Bit and suddenly both users can enter this directory (because of the execution rights), but why isn't it working with this SGID Bit? Is there any chance i just made a mistake with the configuration or am i running into a stupid bug?

Comment: Check that `julia` has group access in their current session (`id`). If you've recently added them to fileadmin they will need to logoff completely. With `systemd` you will also need to kill off the management process, owned by `julia`, that hangs around after logoff

Comment: Please also check that the permissions really are `drwxrws---` and not `drwxrwS---` (the capital signifies SGID but no execute/search permission)